# How to append dynamic values to GET URL in Swift language?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, xcode7, nsurl

I'm very new to Swift i have one simple question

I'm sending GET request in following way

```
loader!.getDataFromRequest(request: NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://......../GetAreaOfOperation?lastCityID=0&batchSize=200")!), dataIndex: -1)
```

now i want send

```
lastCityID = city   // city is an integer which is dynamic   
// instead of lastCityID = 0
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lastCityID = city
loader!.getDataFromRequest(request: NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://......../GetAreaOfOperation?lastCityID=\(lastCityID)&batchSize=200")!), dataIndex: -1)
```

Comment: Thank you! its simple but today is my 3rd working day on Swift :D

Comment: no worries. that's what SO is for... although you could have maybe worked it out taking a look at some resources like https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ ;) could you mark my answer as correct maybe?